# Error installing TuneUp

Tags: windows-7, installation

Recently I removed TuneUp. Now, whenever I try to install a new version of TuneUp, the following error occurs:

> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this
>   package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code
>   is 2753.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this problem happen with tuneUP or any installer?

Comment: this problem happen , just for TuneUp !!!

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: I'm dead sure .

Comment: Which other programs have you tried it on, and have you tried it on anything else that was recently uninstalled?

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following things:

I would download the [Microsoft Installer Cleanup Utility](http://majorgeeks.com/download.php?det=4459) (Microsoft stopped supporting it for their products as they developed newer ways to uninstall Office completely, but it still works, and can help in situations like this one).

Download it to a location, then right-click it and "Run as Administrator" to install it. With Windows 7, it does not know how to create a Startup group, so go to the `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Installer Cleanup` directory. Run Msicuu.exe, and see if TuneUp is listed. If so, highlight it, and click "Remove".

Also download and install [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download). Run the Registry cleaner and "Scan for Issues" and then "Fix selected issues". Run it again until there are no issues.

Then try your install again.

[image]

Comment: I've done it, but the problem is happen again.